# Firebase - how to structurize data

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

I have problem with restructurizing my database.
[image: Database]

So far I have different users storing measurement data. Keys are made of (userId+currentDate). But now I'd like to add sharing this data between users.
Users can send requests for permission to view each other data, but I don't really know where should I store this data.
Should I add additional key(userId) with value (true) inside each node? Can I even update the database in such way - "If user1 is friend with user2, add user1:true to each of users2's nodes"?
How should I proceed?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a second type of node, something like `shared_with_me_<my_user_id>` for the user requesting access to another user data. If agreed by him, you insert this user_id to that node (like `<other_user_id>:true`) so you can query it later.
That said, I really suggest that you start using the Cloud Firestore Database.